# How to make multiple geoJson polygons into multiple clickable events

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I am referencing a geoJson file in the following location to add state polygons to a map of India

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geohacker/india/master/state/india_telengana.geojson

The map is using the googlemaps api

What I would like to do now is make each polygon a clickable event.

In researching I've found that:

- A similar query on stackoverflow has not been answered
- There's much help out there for Leaflet maps, but not googlemaps
- There is some advice suggesting that JSON files such as these are arrays, however the makeup of the JSON files in these examples seem much simpler than the one I'm accessing.  It's easy to see the array identifier in the other examples.  These queries are also only trying to return one property from the array, rather than use the array as a clickable event.

I have now created a JSFiddle but I can't get the final map to load (It loads outside of fiddle):

https://jsfiddle.net/everare/df6jbuft/

The code here shows my attempting to invoke an event using guidance from googlemaps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/combining-data

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="map"style="width:700px;height:700px;border:10px solid black;">              </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Map construction

var map;
  function initMap() {{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 22.71, lng: 82.48},
      zoom: 5,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },

    styles:[
 {    elementType: 'geometry',    stylers: [ {color: '#242f3e'}]},
 {    elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
 {    elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
 {    featureType: 'administrative', elementType: 'geometry', stylers:    [{visibility: 'off'}]},
 {    featureType: 'administrative.locality',elementType:    'labels.text.fill',stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]},
 {    featureType: 'poi', stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
 {    featureType: 'poi', elementType: 'labels.text.fill',stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]},
 {    featureType: 'poi.park',    elementType: 'geometry',    stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}] },
 {    featureType: 'poi.park',   elementType: 'labels.text.fill',    stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road',    stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road',    elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road',    elementType: 'geometry.stroke',    stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]},
  {    featureType: 'road',    elementType: 'labels.icon',    stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road',    elementType: 'labels.text.fill',    stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road.highway', elementType: 'geometry',    stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road.highway', elementType: 'geometry.stroke',stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]},
 {    featureType: 'road.highway', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]},
 {    featureType: 'transit',    stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]},
 {    featureType: 'transit',    elementType: 'geometry',  stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]},
 {    featureType: 'transit.station', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]},
  {    featureType: 'water', elementType: 'geometry',stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]},
  {    featureType: 'water', elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#515c6d' }]},
 {    featureType: 'water', elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',  stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
 }

]  
    });
    }
    // Loads the state boundary polygons from a GeoJSON source. 
    function loadMapShapes() {
        map.data.loadGeoJson('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geohacker/india/master/state/india_telengana.geojson', { idPropertyName: 'STATE' });
    }

   //Responds to the mouse-in event on a map shape (state).
   //@param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e

    function mouseInToRegion(e) {
    // set the hover state so the setStyle function can change the border
    e.feature.setProperty('state', 'hover');
    }

    //Polygon style
    map.data.setStyle({
    fillColor: '#FF8000',
    strokeWeight: 1
    });


    // set up  events for google.maps.Data

    map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseInToRegion);

    // state polygons only need to be loaded once, do them now
    loadMapShapes();

  }
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: white;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px; 
}
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 60px;
```

Comment: Any code to see what have you done up until now? You do a GET request to given address to access the data?

Comment: Have added some code.  Sorry, do you mind elaborating on the GET request?

Comment: HTTP GET request is a way to retrieve external data into your application. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods
I will try to check what's going on later today or tomorrow and let you know if I find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

If your `map.data.loadGeoJson` results in a properly-formatted data object, then the `data` for `map` should already be set. I would `console.log` the data to ensure that the object being produced is what you think it is.

I'm not sure if this is 'canonical' workflow, but my workflow goes as follows:

- Define the map options;
- Create a new map;
- define layers (in your case there would only be 1);
- load data into the layers;
- associate the layers to a map.

So my code for a map with one data layer would look like this:

```
// Step 1. Define Map Options
// note centroid_lat and centroid_lng are evaluated from the data, elsewhere
var tango = {lat: centroid_lat, lng: centroid_lng};
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: tango,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

// Step 2. Make a new Map object
var map=new google.maps.Map($('#mapcanvas')[0], mapOptions);

// Step 3. Make a new Data Layer object
var cLayer = new google.maps.Data();

// Step 4. Put some data into the layer
$.getJSON("json/myfile.json", function(data){
     d1 = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.address)
     cLayer.addGeoJson(d1);
      });

// Step 5. Assign the new layer to the map    
cLayer.setMap(map);
```

The `$.getJSON` and `topojson` should make it clear that this example uses `jquery` and the `d3js` `topojson` library.

Most of the layers I create actually retrieve their data from a PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL database using a PHP script that gets fed some filtering inputs, vets the inputs (to prevent SQL injection etc), then fills in variable names in a query which is passed to PostgreSQL. The query produces GeoJSON and pipes it back to the DOM, where it is attached to the data object.

So my code to populate the data layer would be

```
// db_schema, base_table and thisBox are set elsewhere (thisBox is the 
// bounding box of the viewport)
var c_url="v1/ws_base_fetch.php?schema="+db_schema+"&table="+base_table+"&thisBox="+thisBox;
    // console.log('URL is :'+c_url); // testing only
$.getJSON(
    c_url,
    null,
    function success(data) {
       // Add data to layer, specifying address as idPropertyName
       // this makes address unique, and data with duplicate address 
       // will not be loaded (it will be retrieved though)
       cLayer.addGeoJson(data,{idPropertyName:"address"});
    });
```

Comment: I think $.getJSON method will solve the problem, because in the fiddle the map.data.getGeoJson returns error because MIME type of source data is text/plain and not application/json or sth.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions.  I'm afraid they're beyond my understanding of JSON.  I've tried to understand your response but I cannot determine which data in the JSON file becomes an object to use as a variable in Javascript.  I was hoping that one of the data pieces in the categories within the JSON file could be adapted to become an object, say 'NAME_1'; "Andaman and Nicobar", is this far from reality?  (I have tried using them as they are as object identifiers, no success)

Comment: @ElaineE Do you have anyone that understands these issues around to help? Because one of the things missing in you code is probably Google Maps API key, maybe there is also an issue with response type from your URL etc etc.

Comment: @ DekiChan, thansk for the suggestions.  I have the google maps API in my code, I've used a generic one just for the fiddle.  There is a delay with the URL but I don't think that effects my query here.  I'm just looking for a way to reference a JSON polygon